# Remove empty <p>, but allow only one per group

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, is-empty

I was wondering how to remove empty elements, **but allow only one empty element per group *(next to non-empty one)* ?**

**Something like :**

[image: Remove empty <p>, but allow only one per group]

**Example HTML :**

```
<p>Hello world</p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p> <!--This will remove-->
<p><br></p> <!--This will remove-->
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p><br></p>
<p><br></p> <!--This will remove-->
<p>Eum ne nostro admodum</p>
<p><br></p>
```

**And jQuery for checking the empty elements :**

```
var p_empty = $('p').filter(function(i,v){return $.trim($(v).text()).length===0;});
```

Now I got all empty elements, But any idea how to remove those next empty elements ?

**Workflow :** http://jsfiddle.net/jmy0uzw1/

*PS: I am looking for good JS performance also*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case since you are not using containers, you will have to use sibling selectors `+` and make sure the preceding `p` element itself is not of `.empty`

```
$('p.empty:not(p:not(.empty) + p.empty)').remove();
```

```js
var p_empty = $('p').filter(function(i, v) {
  return $.trim($(v).text()).length === 0;
});

p_empty.addClass('empty');

$('p.empty:not(p:not(.empty) + p.empty)').remove();
```

```css
p {
  padding: 3px 10px;
  background: #eee;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
}
p.empty {
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
  background: #edd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello world</p>
<p>
  <br>
</p>
<p>
  <br>
</p>
<p>
  <br>
</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>
  <br>
</p>
<p>
  <br>
</p>
<p>Eum ne nostro admodum</p>
<p>
  <br>
</p>
```

Comment: Cool one, it's nice to have every thing done with one selector

Comment: @l2aelba, yeah that one! :) hope it helped

Comment: @TwilightSun, it is but if we knew the performance hit, me and you would both cry in corners right now! However, I believe the difference is negligible as long as we are not talking about a huge DOM

Comment: @AmmarCSE, it's just an N to 2N time complexity change. Don't think an optimized algorithm would really help much if the DOM is really huge. I would rather keep the code simple.

Comment: @AmmarCSE What is the use of this  **$('p.empty:not(p:not(.empty))')**

Answer (score 2):

```js
var p_empty = $('p').filter(function(i, v) {
  return $.trim($(v).text()).length === 0;
});

p_empty.addClass('empty');
$('p.empty + p.empty').remove();
```

```css
p {
  padding: 3px 10px;
  background: #eee;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
}
p.empty {
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
  background: #edd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello world</p>
<p>
  <br>
</p>
<p>
  <br>
</p>
<p>
  <br>
</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>
  <br>
</p>
<p>
  <br>
</p>
<p>Eum ne nostro admodum</p>
<p>
  <br>
</p>
```

Try this:

```
$('p.empty + p.empty').remove();
```

Full code

```
var p_empty = $('p').filter(function(i, v) {
  return $.trim($(v).text()).length === 0;
});

p_empty.addClass('empty');
$('p.empty + p.empty').remove();
```

Comment: Nice! This actually works because the first one will always not be included in this selector :) ^1

Answer (score 0):

Just add more to your filter

```
var p_empty = $('p').filter(function(i,v){
    return $.trim($(v).text()).length===0 && $.trim($(v).prev().text()).length===0;
});
```